# How can I create a "push" and "pull" effect?

Tags: jquery, velocity.js

**Update:**
On those examples, we are using *velocity.js*.
But if someone could just drop of an example using **jquery only**, it's fine for me.
Just need to understand the logic, and then I try to adapt.

Please have a quick look here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbVpBO

**ISSUE TRIED TO BE SOLVED**

I wish the butttons, "**Show Less**" and "**Show More**" somehow "**follow**" the slide animations.
At this moment, they just "jump", making this animation anything but smoother. 
In a way that, when the content goes up, the button also goes up, and when the content goes down, the content also goes down. :(

**Can anyone help me out please?**

I'm relying on *complete* form Velocity.js, while this is understandable, perhaps that's were I'm doing it wrong. :(

Please advice:

```
complete: function() {
                    $(btShowMoreEventInfo).hide();
                    $(btShowLessEventInfo).show();
                }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="event-wrapper">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.
</div>
<a href="#" class="bt-show-hide-event-info">
        <p class="bt-show-more-event-info">SHOW MORE <br /><img src="/images/eventos/showMore.png" alt="show more" /></p>
        <p class="bt-show-less-event-info">SHOW LESS <br /><img src="/images/eventos/showLess.png" alt="show less" /></p>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.event-wrapper {
  display: none;  
}

.bt-show-less-event-info {
  display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery('.bt-show-hide-event-info').on('click', function(evt) {
    var eventWrapper = $(this).siblings('.event-wrapper').eq(0);
    var btShowMoreEventInfo = $(this).find('.bt-show-more-event-info');
    var btShowLessEventInfo = $(this).find('.bt-show-less-event-info');

    if ($(eventWrapper).is(':visible')) {
        $(eventWrapper).velocity(
            "transition.slideUpOut",
            {
                duration: 500,
                complete: function() {
                    $(btShowLessEventInfo).hide();
                    $(btShowMoreEventInfo).show();
                }
            }
        );
    } else {
        $(eventWrapper).velocity(
            "transition.slideDownIn",
            {
                duration: 500,
                complete: function() {
                    $(btShowMoreEventInfo).hide();
                    $(btShowLessEventInfo).show();
                }
            });
    }

    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: If I understood it correct. Why don't you use jquery's `slideToggle()/slideUp()/slideDown()` methods.

Comment: The slide and fade are working fine. I'm not attached to anything. It could be just jquery, just velocity. The point is: I don't understand how can I make those "show more", "show less" buttons, to follow the slide effect. Like pushing and pulling something.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps, check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7od6jom/1)

```
<div class="event-wrapper">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.
</div>
<a href="#" id="less" class="clickMe">Show Less...
</a>
<a href="#" id="more" style="display: none" class="clickMe">Show More...
</a>


$().ready(function(){
$(".clickMe").click(function(e)
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(".event-wrapper").slideToggle("fast", function(){
           if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
               $("#less").show();
               $("#more").hide();
           }
           else
           {
               $("#more").show();
               $("#less").hide();
           }
       })                   
   })
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for being available Cyberpks, indeed that's more what I was looking for. You use a single element, and then change their information, using .html(), the thing is, that "show more" and "show less" cannot be written on the js. Must be on html. I will study it a little bit more. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, but I'm trying with several elements on the page, and it shows, or hides *all*, instead of just *this* element. Sorry for not mention that on my Original Question. I will mark your answer as useful.